# Servlet Java - ArrayList output

Tags: java, servlets, arraylist

I have a set of numbers that I get the user to enter and then add them to an array-list. Then I sort them and have to print them back out to the user. My problem is that I cant get them to print in a format outside the [ ].

how can I get the numbers of an array-list to output in the format:
  1,
  2,
  3,

and not:
  [1, 2, 3]

Comment: please first of all show us some source code.

Comment: Don't use `toString()` method, instead create your method which will print according to your choice.

Comment: if you use toString() method then use replace like this someObj.toString().replace("[","").replace("]","")

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are directly printing array.Instead of that,you need to iterate iver elements.
You can iterate over arraylist and print.

```
    for(int num : list)
    {
        System.out.println(num);
    }
```

If you need "," then you can append that while iterating

```
    for(int num : list)
    {
        System.out.println(num + ",");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, been trying to figure it out for so long. This actually worked

Answer (score 0):

Try something like Guava Joiner
https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/StringsExplained

```
Joiner.on(",").join(arraylist);
```

before printing the array value